# Assembly Language and Platform Independence

Tags: assembly

I am confused regarding platform dependence. I would like to get this straight. So, if I understand it correctly, particular hardware architecture will have a particular instruction set.

Right? Eg. if we are talking about say Intel 8086 processor, then there is a specific instruction set for this processor. If I code in this instruction set it means that I am coding in the assembly language supported by Intel 8086. Right?

Now this particular processor architecture can be used by a variety of machines and operating systems. Eg. A MAC using Mountain Lion OSX, a Lenovo machine using Ubuntu as its OS and a Sony VAIO machine using Windows 7 as its OS, all of these machines can have their underlying processor architecture as Intel 8086. Right?

So now if I write code (to say add 2 numbers) in assembly language for Intel 8086 processor, this code should run without any problems on all the 3 machines mentioned above. And a common assembler should be able to convert this code to the machine level code on all these 3 machines. Right?

So now, where does platform dependence come into picture here? Since the asm code is being written for the same underlying processor architecture, should it not just run on all platforms?

I am just trying to figure out where am I going wrong and getting confused. What am I missing here? Please bear with me if the question sounds confusing or stupid.

Comment: Physical hardware exclusively does not a "platform" make.

Comment: How would you run your program? Something has to run it (a BIOS, a Windows system, a Linux one....)

Comment: This question should be migrated to programmers stackexchange

Comment: Adding 2 numbers is the _easy_ bit. Now consider how you get those numbers into and out of the processor without having to interact with a particular OS...

Comment: @Notlikethat I read it here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/assembly_introduction.htm that :- "Each family of processors has its own set of instructions for handling various operations like getting input from keyboard, displaying information on screen and performing various other jobs. These set of instructions are called 'machine language instructions'." So does it still need to interact with the OS ?

Comment: What's the closest to assembly language that is platform independent?

Comment: @Anatoly That would be C.

Comment: @qre0ct If you want to see any visual evidence that your code actually did anything, yes. I could write `mov ax,40 jmp $` and it would run on any 8086-based machine, and have the same result regardless of operating system, but other than using an external debugging device to view the register state I'd have no way of knowing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'll give you a bad car analogy as to why there are problems.

Cars of all brands are constructed with screws and bolts of the same type (8086 code)

And although you can take a screw from a Ford (Windows) and screw it into a Toyota (OSX), you can't take a body panel from a Ford (Internet explorer) and bolt it onto a Toyota (OSX).

The panels may be attached with the same sorts of screws and bolts, but the panels will never fit between the two brands.

Thus while you can use the same fundamental instructions between Windows and OSX to build basic things, once you start building things in the style of the OS you can no longer interchange them.  And that heads you down the road of platform dependence.

(I told you it would be a bad analogy)

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately your assembly language program isn't going to get very far without using an API and ABI for input and output. And the API and ABI *are* platform dependent.

Comment: To give another perspective on this: [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/) implements the Windows platform ABI (including executable loader, etc) to allow Windows programs to be run on other platforms.  That is, different platforms (operating systems) implement different ABIs, but there's nothing magical about that, and yes, the underlying machine code is "platform independent", it's the interfaces between components that are platform specific.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, "8086" is no longer strictly accurate. There have been number extensions to the instruction set since its first release, in particular when it was extended to 64 bits. So, one source of incompatibility already is whether the code is intended to run in 64 or 32 bit mode (or even 16 bit mode).

In any event The problem is the interface between hardware and operating system. Assembler code for the x86 instruction set will be the same for all three, but the resulting machine code may/will still be incompatible. Different OSes may use different constants, conventions, or schematics for things like system call tables, function entry and exit, and stack allocation. For example, in 64-bit, most x86 Unices use registers for the first 6 arguments and then push the rest to the stack, whereas Windows uses registers for only the first 4, and pushes an additional 32 byte field to the stack to mirror those registers on every function call. Which registers are used also varies, e.g. Windows puts the first non floating point argument in RCX but Unix uses RDI.
you
It's possible to account for all of this using compiler macros, but then you don't have binary compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

x86 is a particularly painful instruction set in many ways.  In particular you cannot even say that a simple addition of two numbers in assembly language is portable across many x86 computers because there have been too many different assemblers with at least two major flavors of syntax.

So no, you cannot say that if you took a single line of asm adding two numbers that it would port.

You might say that about some other instruction sets, but that would only be academic because as Peter M said, the bolts and the sheet metal might all be from the same place but the doors are not interchangeable.

I can take the same bricks and the same mortar and build different, incompatible buildings, meant for different purposes.  So the bricklaying skills are portable but what we build with them are not.

Same goes for many other programming languages, some of which were designed initially to be portable.